# Ionic can't pass information in $rootScope

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I want to pass the data in $rootScope of users

Here is my factroty

**userProvider.js**

```
'use strict';

app
.factory('userProvider', function ($rootScope , $http , $location) {
var url='http://127.0.0.1:100/suitecrm/API/Login.php';
function logIn(user) {
  $http.post(url,user)
    .success(function (response) {
      $rootScope.user=response.data;
      $location.path('/profile');
      console.log(response);

    });
}

return {
  logIn: logIn
}
});
```

`console.log(response);` show me data normally in the console

Here is the controller of the profile which i want to show information of current user

```
 'use strict';

app
.controller('Profile', function ($scope ,userProvider, $rootScope) {
    console.log($rootScope.user);
 })
 ;
```

But in the console of chrome shows me undefined.

Here is Routing.js

```
'use strict';

 var cacheActive=false;

 app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
 $stateProvider
 .state('homapage', {
  cache: cacheActive,
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: 'js/views/homepage/Login.html',
  controller:'homepageLogin'
})
.state('profile', {
  cache: cacheActive,
  url:'/profile',
  templateUrl:'js/views/profiles/profile.html',
  controller:'profile'
})
});
```

How can i pass the data in $rootScope and show them in the view of the controller?

Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't called the `logIn()` function from your `userProvider` service yet.

```
app
.controller('Profile', function ($scope ,userProvider, $rootScope) {
    userProvider.logIn($scope.user);
    console.log($rootScope.user);
 })
```

But,

I suggest you do it without using `$rootScope`. What you can is from your factory, you may want to return the data after the call:

```
app.
factory('userProvider', function($http){

 var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:100/suitecrm/API/Login.php';

 function logIn(user) {
   $http.post(url,user).success(function (response) {
     return response;
   });
 }

 return {
   logIn: logIn
 }

})
```

Then, again, without using `$rootScope`, on your `Profile` controller you can do:

```
app.
controller('Profile', function($scope, userProvider){
  $scope.user = {...}
  $scope.currentUser = userProvider.logIn($scope.user);
  console.log($scope.currentUser)
})
```

For the location routing, please do it inside your controller, instead of the factory.